# Powershell change directory and run command

Tags: powershell

New to PS.

I'm trying to run a script that gets the current path, opens a new PS window from a subdirectory and leaves the PS window open, and runs a command from there.

The command varies, my example just uses write-ouput, but it would be something more like "dotnet watch"

Something like this:

```
$dir = $PSScriptRoot
$folder = '\MyFolder'
$subdir = "$dir$folder"
$message = "hello world"

$process = Start-Process powershell.exe ("-noexit " + "cd $subdir" + "Write-output $message")
```

This runs without error, but of course it opens 2 PS windows, I'm wanting to do this all from one.

```
$dir = $PSScriptRoot
$folder = '\MyFolder'
$subdir = "$dir$folder"
$message = "hello world"

$process = Start-Process powershell.exe ("-noexit " + "cd $subdir") 
$process = Start-Process powershell.exe ("-noexit " + "Write-output $message")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What follows `-noexit` is implicitly passed to the `-Command` [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) parameter and must therefore be valid PowerShell code, with multiple statements separated with `;`

`"` characters that are to be part of the PowerShell code must be escaped as `\"` to protect them from the initial command line parsing.

Therefore (using a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) for quoting convenience and readability):

```bash
Start-Process powershell.exe @"
-noexit "cd \"$subdir\"; Write-output '$($message -replace "'", "''")'"
"@
```

`$message -replace "'", "''"` escapes any `'` in the value of `$message` as `''`, so they can be used inside a `'...'` string - with your sample value, this replacement happens not to be necessary, but enclosing the up-front expanded value of `$message` in `'...'` - i.e. using *embedded quoting* - *is* necessary: otherwise, you'd execute `Write-Output hello world`, which prints *two* lines, because `hello` and `world` are separate arguments.

It also isn't strictly necessary to enclose the (implied) `-Command` argument in `"..."` overall, but not doing so can have side effects, namely *whitespace normalizing* (e.g., `'hello        world'` would turn into `'hello world'`).